# Error on inflating a fragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have a fragment and I am inflating it like below, but it is giving runtime error:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View jobsView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_job_information, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) jobsView.findViewById(R.id.textView);


        if (jobInfo == null) {
            EmployerHistory jobsQuery=new EmployerHistory();
            jobInfo = jobsQuery.getJobInfo(employerName, position);
        }

        textView.setText(jobInfo.get("jobName").toString());

        return jobsView;
    }
```

Its corresponding layout is:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/jobInfoFragment">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.ankit.job_depot.employer.view.JobInformation">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</fragment>
```

Actually I am already on a fragment with listview and when user clicks on an element of listview that fragment needs to get changed by a new fragment, in my new fragment I have:
l

```
istViewJobHistory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                JobInformation newFragment =  new JobInformation();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.listViewJobHistory, newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                transaction.commit();
            }

        });
```

I am getting the following exception:

> 07-28 18:49:39.681  14474-14474/com.example.ankit.job_depot
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.ankit.job_depot, PID: 14474
>       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>               at com.example.ankit.job_depot.employer.view.JobInformation.onCreateView(JobInformation.java:45)
>               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)

Comment: Is your Activity extending FragmentActivity ?

Comment: it is extending Fragment

Comment: `Fragment` is not in the `Activity` type hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your main Activity should extend FragmentActivity

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to use FragmentActivity, can't I switch the content of fragment i.e. I want the fragment content to get updated when list item is selected.

Comment: No, you don't have to change your fragment class, you will have an Activity class which needs to extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity, no change to your Fragment code.